# Как вывести 2 знака после точки например 0.01 JS

Tags: javascript

Доброй ночи, ломаю себе голову с выводом двух знаков после запятой.

Делаю значения clickPower = 0.01;
Далее перехожу на сайт делаю 6 кликов и получаю число 0.060000000000000005 а по идеи должен получить 0.06, первые 5 кликов отображает число правильно 0.01 0.02.
На просторах интернета нашел .toFixed(2) но когда я добавляю его к

```
document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = clicks.toFixed(2) + clickPower;
```

В конечном итоге я получаю число 0.01.01 когда делаешь клик еще раз получаем 0.02.01 Не пойму почему появляется .01 в конце.

В консоли все показывает как и должно быть

```
var clicks = 0;
var clickPower = 0.01;

const onClick = () => {
    document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = clicks + clickPower;
    clicks = clicks + clickPower;

    console.info(clicks.toFixed(2));
}

document.getElementById('big-btn').addEventListener('click', onClick)

<div class="balance__container">
   <div id="clicks-count" class="balance">0</div>
</div>
<div id="big-btn" class="poiner">
   <div draggable="false" class="pointer__img"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `Number.toFixed()` возвращает `string`, а не `number`.

Поэтому оператор `+` применимый к строке конкатенирует, а не складывает.

Вам строку нужно обратно привести к числу:

```js
document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = +clicks.toFixed(2) + clickPower; ;
//                                                  ^ 
// + приведет number к string
// или можно использовать parseInt(clicks.toFixed(2));
```

Или:

```
document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = (clicks + clickPower).toFixed(2) ;
```

Прочитайте внимательно топик на MDN по методу `toFixed()`, там все это описывается.

Вот еще [статья](https://medium.com/@sergeybulavyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-javascript-35a15ddfc333) про приведение типов в JS.

Comment: Спасибо

Одна проблема пропала, есть еще одна когда делаешь первые 6 кликов выводит 0.060000000000000005 данное число, после делаешь 2 клика число 0.07 - 0.08 и потом опять 0.09999999999999999

Comment: @itscoldhell дополнил. Во втором варианте такого не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за второй вариант, очень помогли. Сутки голову ломал себе)